# Remote Desktop on laptop freezes if idle

Tags: laptop, remote-desktop, ping, connection, timeout

OK, after a few days, I have finally solved this but I am posting it here in case anyone else encounters it. Really weird problem.

My RDP session to my new laptop would be stable as long as I was doing something within the session, even just moving the mouse around every couple of moments. The overnight backup went through without problem last night. But if I left the laptop idle for more than a few moments and returned back to it, it was disconnected and would take many seconds to reconnect. Very annoying.

Scenario:
Windows 2012 server used as my main computer with multiple monitors. I use it to connect to my laptop using RDP (I prefer big , multiple monitors when working).

Server has two NICs to the router on separate IPs (one is emergency backup). Cisco WAP371 directly connected to the router for 5GHz for an android tablet, cell phone, LG TV, and laptop. Cisco WAP121 connected via a switch from the router for an HP printer (cause it won't connect on the WAP371). A second printer is attached via the switch connected to the router. Oh, and my old laptop to one or the other WAP.

I read through as many posts as I could and have tried resetting all the things everyone talks about on the NICs, in services, in Windows, firewalls, etc.

Finally set up pings on my server and laptops to all devices and each other and watched.

I was getting ping timeouts on the main NIC to the the router, both laptops, and both WAPs - not always at the same time. But no timeout to the printer on the WAP121! That was weird.

I tried connecting the laptop to the WAP121 and no change. Turned off all devices one by one and shutdown all VMs. No change. Tried changing cables.

With many of the alterations, the pings would all work again for a couple of minutes.

Eventually I switched the roles on the NICs using my backup NIC for the main traffic to the router. And voila! it all worked! And the network was so much faster!

The only explanation I can come up with is that the "bad" NIC worked marginally on larger packets. I cannot explain why the pings timed out to the router port, but worked okay on the printer on the WAP121 even though those pings had to go though the same router port. (I confirmed by disconnecting the second cable to the router.)

So for anyone trying to diagnose RDP timeouts, beware that there could be a flaky Ethernet port somewhere along the traffic pathway that cannot be determined simply by studying which ports timed out on pings.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.